# double awk commands in same pipe?

Tags: mysql, awk

Hello I'm trying to do something like this but it wont work, can you guys tell me help me out?

```
/usr/bin/mysql -B -r -h ******** -u******* -p****** -D***** \
    -e'SELECT `username`, `uid`, `gid`, `homedir` FROM `some_table`)' | \
        awk '{print $1":x:"$2":"$3"::"$4":/usr/sbin/nologin"}' >> /tmp/file1 ;
        awk '{print $1":"$5":13753:0:99999:7:::"}'>>/tmp/file2
```

Changing ";" to "&&" doesn't work either.
Both file1 and file2 is created, but only file1 contains data.
So basically what I want to do is using the same variables for two commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -B -r -h ******** -u******* -p****** -D***** \
    -e'SELECT `username`, `uid`, `gid`, `homedir` FROM `some_table`)' | \
        awk '{ print $1":x:"$2":"$3"::"$4":/usr/sbin/nologin" >> "/tmp/file1"; 
               print $1":"$5":13753:0:99999:7:::" >> "/tmp/file2" }'
```

Comment: Good call, get awk to do both operations in one call. I was thinking of the more generic case :)

Answer (score 2):

When you want to run two different commands on the same incoming pipe data, you need to use an intermediate file:

```
TMPFILE="$(mktemp)"
/usr/bin/mysql -B -r -h ******** -u******* -p****** -D***** \
               -e'SELECT `username`, `uid`, `gid`, `homedir` FROM `some_table`)' >"$TMPFILE"
awk '{print $1":x:"$2":"$3"::"$4":/usr/sbin/nologin"}' <"$TMPFILE" >>/tmp/file1
awk '{print $1":"$5":13753:0:99999:7:::"}' <"$TMPFILE" >>/tmp/file2
rm -f "$TMPFILE"
```

But as [quanta writes](https://serverfault.com/questions/322594/double-awk-commands-in-same-pipe/322613#322613), you can ask a single `awk` instance to do both operations.

Answer (score 1):

You've made quite a mess, starting with the formatting of your question (see what I've done above which should make things below more clear).

***First problem:***
  If you have a semicolon (`;`) or a "continue-on-success (`&&`) you are running two separate sets of commands.
Completely separate. It's like you ran one, hit enter and then ran the other.
This means your second `awk` is looking on stdin for input, and not finding anything it's giving you no output (which is why `file2` is empty)

***Second Problem:***
Separate instances of `awk` can't share variables.  Either you want the second `awk` to chew on the output of the MySQL query, or you want it to chew on the output of the first `awk`.
Since you've got 5 variables in your second `awk` I'm assuming the latter.

***Solution***
Run the first half of the command list (everything up to the semicolon).
Now run the second awk, and specify an input file (`awk '{print $1":"$5":13753:0:99999:7:::"}' /tmp/file1 >> /tmp/file2`).

Comment: Thank you!
Sorry for the messy question, was in a bit of hurry when I wrote it, Ive think about it next time!

Comment: No worries - That was more a "If you format your commands so they're pretty sometimes the answer jumps out" note than a "your question is ugly so I'm going to beat you with a dirty sock" one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your command as shown will never work, as processing is entirely sequential, and the output of mysql is already used up by the first awk statement.

I would simply move all that to a tiny bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mycmd="SELECT `username`, `uid`, `gid`, `homedir` FROM `some_table`"
while read -r username, uid, gid, homedir; do
printf "%s:x:%s:%s::%s:/usr/sbin/nologin" "$username" "$uid" "$gid" "$homedir" >> /tmp/file1
printf "%s:%s:13753:0:99999:7:::" "$username" "missing variable" >>/tmp/file2
done <(/usr/bin/mysql -B -r -h * -u* -p* -D* -e "$mycmd")
```

UNtested, visit the [Wooledge Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) for more bash magic than you knew existed :)

Comment: I'll keep that site in mind!